# Angular ignoring JSON fields on Object instantiation

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to query the wagtail API that will return JSON in a very unfriendly format.

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "meta": {
        "type": "home.HomePage",
        "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pages/3/"
    },
    "parent": null,
    "title": "Homepage",
    "body": "<h2>cool an h2 fgf</h2>",
    "main_image": {
        "id": 1,
        "meta": {
            "type": "wagtailimages.Image",
            "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/images/1/"
        }
    },
    "header_image": {
        "id": 1,
        "meta": {
            "type": "wagtailimages.Image",
            "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/images/1/"
        }
    },
    "show_in_menus": true,
    "full_url": "/media/images/Background-4.original.jpg"
}
```

All I really want from that is a class like this.

```
export class HomePage {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  full_url: string;

}
```

But whenever I get back from the data back from my service and try and log it, it is undefined.

Is there any way for me to ignore the fields I don't want from a JSON in typescript?

The service I am using is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {HomePage} from "./HomePage";

@Injectable()
export class HomePageService {

  constructor(private http: Http){
  }

  getHomePage(GUID: number): Observable<HomePage>{
    return this.http
      .get("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pages/" + GUID + "/")
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {}
  }
  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

And the component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {HomePageService} from './home-page.service';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {HomePage} from "./HomePage";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css'],
  providers: [HomePageService]
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  id: number;
  private sub: any;
  public homePage: HomePage;
  errorMessage: string;
  constructor(private homePageService : HomePageService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
    });
    this.homePageService.getHomePage(this.id)
      .subscribe(
        homePage => this.homePage = new HomePage(homePage),
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error,
        () => console.log(this.homePage.full_url)
      );
    console.log(this.id);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: could you add code for the service that is getting the data?

Comment: Added the component and the service code, thanks.

Comment: `homePage => this.homePage = new HomePage(homePage)` - do you have a constructor for `HomePage` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`homePage => this.homePage = new HomePage(homePage)` - in your code I don't see a constructor defined for `HomePage` class. So when you pass the `homePage` object to it, nothing happens. Try this:

```
export class HomePage{
    id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  full_url: string;

  constructor(homePageObj: any)
  {
      if (homePageObj)
      {
          this.id = homePageObj.id;
          this.title = homePageObj.title;
          this.body = homePageObj.body;
          this.full_url = homePageObj.full_url;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, but it didn't work. homePageObj is not populated with anything. honestly, I thought the constructors auto-populate when you define class variables as in the Heroes example they don't fill the constructor like this.

Comment: There was actually an issue with the service here.

return body.data || {} 

needed to be 

return body || {}

I just copied that code from somewhere badly. I believe that this answers the question I asked, though. As when the parameters don't match the response body correctly you will need angular will throw an error and you should define constructor manually. Thank you

Comment: Another thing you can try is `return <HomePage>body.data || {}`.

Comment: Thanks that will mean I don't have to instantiate the object in the component =)